# vscode: how to get offset of cursor in the document?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I am working on a vscode extension .. I want to get the cursor position reference to the whole document, for example if I've the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<|body>
  <div>
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the cursur was inside the body tag (the place of the `|` sign in the code above), the result I want is 178 which is the index of the character if you start counting all characters in the document (including white spaces) from the start.

I tried this code

```
    const position = editor.selection.active;
    console.log(position);
```

but it gives the line and the position of the character in that line, which is not what I need.

Is there any way to get the desired output ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following call

```
editor.document.offsetAt(editor.selection.active)
```

A `Selection` has 4 `Position` properties:

- `start`, `end` : position relative to begin of file
- `anchor`, `active` : position of begin and stop of cursor making the selection

Comment: `editor.selection.active` is the position of the cursor.  The start of the selection may not be where the cursor is.

Comment: This code works if there is no selection, but may or may not if there is a selection (depends on the direction the selection was made), hence `active` is the way to go to be sure you get the cursor position in all cases, selection or not.

Comment: Note the above comment was referencing the prior revision of this answer, which was using `editor.selection.start`.

Answer (score 3):

```
let activeEditor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
let document = activeEditor.document;
let curPos = activeEditor.selection.active;
let offset = document.offsetAt(curPos);
```