# Is there an API to access cursor location history?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I don't like the default behavior of the cursor history navigation (with the side buttons on my mouse). I decided to make my first extension to satisfy my needs, but I didn't find a way to access the cursor history. Is there an API for that?

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65261663/vscode-how-to-get-position-of-cursor-in-the-document

Comment: @Al.G. I don't really want to keep my own cursor history as that would complicate things. I would rather use an API if there is one.